# Observable.Generate in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, corecursion

.NET Reactive Extensions has a neat method to generate sequences using corecursion which is called [Observable.Generate](https://www.google.se/#q=Observable.Generate).

Is there analogues method in RxJava that allows data generation via corecursion? If not, could it be implemented based on existing methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an exact match but we have `SyncOnSubscribe` (and `AsyncOnSubscriber`) that can generate values, for example:

```
@Test
public void testRange() {
    final int start = 1;
    final int count = 4000;
    OnSubscribe<Integer> os = SyncOnSubscribe.createStateful(new Func0<Integer>(){
        @Override
        public Integer call() {
            return start;
        }}, 
        new Func2<Integer, Observer<? super Integer>, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Integer state, Observer<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext(state);
                if (state == count) {
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
                return state + 1;
            }
        });

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Observer<Object> o = mock(Observer.class);
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(o);

    Observable.create(os).subscribe(o);

    verify(o, never()).onError(any(TestException.class));
    inOrder.verify(o, times(count)).onNext(any(Integer.class));
    inOrder.verify(o).onCompleted();
    inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}
```